# Copying an object to another object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm making a small example to display JSON (key and value). When I copy the JSON to another variable, I've tried to delete key `Age` and re-displayed the first JSON. Key `Age` in the first JSONhas been deleted, too.

```js
$('button').click(function () {
  var json = {};
  json['Name'] = 'Hermione';
  json['Age'] = 19;
  
  for (i in json) {
    $('body').append($('<p>').text(i + ': ' + json[i]))
  }
   
  var copy = json;
  delete copy['Age'];
  
  for (i in json) {
    $('body').append($('<p>').text(i + ': ' + json[i]))
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
```

So, my question is: Copying an object to another object means nothing in JavaScript, right?

I think that because when I copied it, it's still operating on the main version (`json`), not on the copy version (`copy`).

Comment: You're not copying the object when you do copy = json. You're just creating another reference to the same object.

Comment: Why are you referring to your objects as "JSON", which is a string-based format for exchanging information between eg server and client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var copy = json;` will create a reference of the `json` object.

> Javascript objects are `mutable`, it means if you remove property from one object then another object referring that object will also lose that key.

If you do not want that to happen then  look for `deep copy` of javascript objects which will create new independent objects.

Comment: This has nothing to do with mutability.

Comment: @torazaburo sir, what I meant by _mutable_ is _dependent_ with each other. Isn't that correct ?

Answer (score 2):

var copy = json; simply creates a new variable called "copy" (a pointer), which points to the object "json". You haven't "copied" anything. You are simply saying I am going to give json another name, and the name is "copy". If you want to recursively clone an object, you'll need to write a function that does it or use underscore/lodash's [_.cloneDeep()](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep).

```
var objects = [{ 'a': 1 }, { 'b': 2 }];

var deep = _.cloneDeep(objects);
console.log(deep[0] === objects[0]);
// → false
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you simply assigned the same object to another variable.
If you really want to copy the object you could use the extend function of jquery.

```
// Shallow copy
var copy = jQuery.extend({}, json);

// Deep copy
var copy= jQuery.extend(true, {}, json);
```

See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object) for deeper information about "cloning" js objects.

Answer (score 1):

your `var copy = json` is  a reference to `json`, not a copy of `json`.
It is simply a pointer to the same place in the memory.
So whenever you say `delete copy["Age"]`, you are refering to `json["Age"]`

Comment: I think you mean "a pointer to **the same** place in memory".

Comment: That is indeed what I mean, sorry for the confusion. I changed it now.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot simply copy objects to another variable like `var copy = json;` because objects are assigned by reference.

try,

```
var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json));
```

Comment: Of the many ways to deep-clone an object, that is certainly one, but by no means the best one. See related questions.

Answer (score -1):

Its Working

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var json = {};
            json['Name'] = 'Hermione';
            json['Age'] = 19;
            for (i in json) {
                $('body').append($('<p>').text(i + ': ' + json[i]))
            }
            var copy = json;
            delete copy['Age'];
            for (i in json) {
                $('body').append($('<p>').text(i + ': ' + json[i]))
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" class="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Click me"> 
</body>
```

Comment: What is working, how?